# socket.io - send notification to admin when order place in WooCommerce

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, socket.io

I have create script for Nodejs server working properly. Connect with contact form 7 when contact request send admin get notification and notification counter get updated. I have same logic implement for WooCommerce thank you page when order place send notification. Its not working there.

- send notification to admin when WooCommerce order received
- is it possible to get notification for different site?

**Code Woocoomerce**

script.js when thank you page load

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 var socketIO = io("http://localhost:3000");

 var userId = 10;
 socketIO.emit("connected", userId);
 socketIO.emit("newNotification", userId);
 // console.log("Emit executed");
});
```

admin-script.js its in admin

```
 // connect with Node JS server
 var socketIO = io("http://localhost:3000");
 
 // connect user with Node JS server
 var userId = 10;
 socketIO.emit("connected", userId);


 // when a new notification is received
 socketIO.on("newNotification", function (data) {
     var counter = jQuery('span.notificationcounter').val() + data;
    jQuery('span.notificationcounter').val(counter );
 });
```

**NodeJS server Code**

```
// initialize express server
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
 
// create http server from express instance
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
 
// include socket IO
var socketIO = require("socket.io")(http, {
    allowEIO3: true,
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost"]
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("Vasim Shaik");
  });

// start the HTTP server at port 3000
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    // console.log("Server started running...");
 
    // an array to save all connected users IDs
    var users = [];
 
    // called when the io() is called from client
    socketIO.on("connection", function (socket) {
        
        // called manually from client to connect the user with server
        socket.on("connected", function (id) {

            users[id] = socket.id;
            socketIO.to(users[id]).emit("connected", id);

            
        });
        // when a new notification is received
        socket.on("newNotification", function (userId) {
         
            // send notification to the selected user
            socketIO.to(users[userId]).emit("newNotification", {message:"new contact request",count:1});

        });

        // when a new notification is received
        socket.on("readNotification", function (userId) {
         
            // send notification to the selected user
            socketIO.to(users[userId]).emit("readNotification", userId);
        });
    });
});
```

**Implemented Code - Updated answer :**

[image]

In admin script in WordPress :

[image]

In Express server :
[image]

Comment: you can not use socket for different site. The case is how do you connect to socket on a different site? you cannot.

Comment: we can connect socket to server but request can be raised from any website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried WooCommerce Webhooks?

From [WooCommerce documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/):

> A Webhook is an event notification sent to a URL of your choice. Users can configure them to trigger events on one site to invoke behavior on another.
> Webhooks are useful for integrating with third-party services and other external API that support them.

A mininmal implementation for your use case would be along the lines below.

##### 1. Create a webhook in WooCommerce that's triggered whenever an order is placed

- Go to: WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Webhooks
- Select **Create a new webhook** (first incident) or **Add webhook**

We will need to enter/fill in details for each settings field. I've listed the most relevant below.

- Topic: **Order Created**
- Delivery URL: `https://example.com/api/order-webhook` (this is the URL to which the Webhook payload will be sent)
- Secret: `some-big-bold-secret` (if provided, **Secret Key** is included in the request headers with a hash representing the sent webhook)
- API Version: **WP REST API Integration v3**

##### 2. Create a new URL endpoint on your Express server to receive notifications

The webhook from the previous step will send a `POST` request to our server each time an order is created. Once we receive the request we'll extract the `payload`, or our [data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object#:%7E:text=In%20the%20field%20of%20programming,call%20is%20an%20expensive%20operation.) (DTO), from the request's body.

```
app.post('/order-webhook', function(req, res){
  // check if it's a valid request from WooCommerce
  if (!req.headers['Secret-Key']) return res.status(401).end()

  // parse our data
  const payload = req.body 

  // we could use any event handler here
  socketIO.emit("newNotification", payload)

  // end response
  res.status(200).end()
})
```

##### 3. Handle the event within your Express server with Socket.io

The logic here is similar to OP's implementation. We can propagate the received data to specific channels, save it on a database, add to a local cache, append on a `log.txt` file, render on a page, etc.

```
 socketIO.on("newNotification", function (data) { 
    // our payload or dto
    console.log('New Order Received: ', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) 
    
    // implementation
    let current = jQuery('span.notificationcounter').val()
    let updated = current++

    jQuery('span.notificationcounter').val(updated)
 })
```

Let me know if you have any issues and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for answer I will check let you know

Comment: I have updated answer. getting issue 502 error. server is running

Comment: webhook request body always null @Moa

Comment: The week got into the middle of things. I'll make a quick repro. Bear with me.

Comment: Its working. Need to know what if multiple client and single server.

Comment: Cool. Just to catch-up, as I'm looking into it right now: did you manage to get rid of both `502` and `req.body` being always `null`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189293/socketio-p2p-connection-with-nodejs-and-wordpress